# Solve $ y''+\omega^2y = \tan(\beta t) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\omega \neq 0$, $\beta \neq 0$ and $\beta \neq \omega$.

Solve the following ODE:

$$ y''+\omega^2y = \tan(\beta t), t \in \left] -\frac{\pi}{2\beta},\frac{\pi}{2\beta} \right[ $$

The associated homogeneous equation is:

$$ y''+\omega^2y = 0 $$

This is the simple harmonic oscillator equation and two linearly independent solutions are:

$$ \phi_1(t)=\sin(\omega t), \phi_2(t)=\cos(\omega t) $$

Let $c_1,c_2 \in \Bbb{R} $. The general solution is:

$$ \phi(t)=c_1\phi_1(t)+c_2\phi_2(t) $$

Now I have to find a particular solution $w(t)$ of the inhomogeneous equation. Finally, the solution of the ODE will be:

$$ y(t)=c_1\phi_1(t)+c_2\phi_2(t) + w(t) $$

Now, in order to do this, we've studied the method of variation of constants. The idea of this method is that the arbitrary constants in the general solution of the homogeneous equation are replaced by functions of $t$, that must be chosen such that inhomogeneous equation is fulfilled. So, I'm looking for a particular solution such that:

$$ w(t)=c_1(t)\phi_1(t)+c_2(t)\phi_2(t) $$

This approach led me to the system

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l}
c_1'(t) \phi_1(t)+c_2'(t) \phi_2(t)=0\\
c_1'(t) \phi_1'(t)+c_2'(t) \phi_2'(t)=\tan(\beta t)
\end{array}\right. $$

which is equivalent to

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l}
c_1'(t) \sin(\omega t)+c_2'(t) \cos(\omega t)=0\\
c_1'(t) \omega \cos(\omega t)-c_2'(t) \omega \sin(\omega t)=\tan(\beta t)
\end{array}\right. $$

I tried to solve this system but without success.

How can I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good start. Now you have a linear system of two equations for your two unknowns $c_1'$ and $c_2'$, so you should be able to solve for them (using Gaussian elimination, or multiplying by the inverse matrix, or however you prefer to do it), and once you have done that, you can integrate them separately.

Comment: Your solution involves integrals $\int c_1'(t)\;dt$ and $\int c_2'(t)\;dt$, which turn out to be  non-elementary.

Comment: I obtained:

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l}
c_1'(t) =\frac{\tan(\beta t) \cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\\
c_2'(t) =-\frac{\tan(\beta t) \sin(\omega t)}{\omega}
\end{array}\right. $$

Now I have to solve the following integrals, $ \int c_1'(t)\;dt $ and $ \int c_2'(t)\;dt $, which turn out to be non-elementary. Leaving out the explicit solution of the integrals, perhaps it is not a beautiful solution, but the following function is still a particular solution

$$ w(t)=\sin(\omega t) \int c_1'(t)\;dt  + \cos(\omega t) \int c_2'(t)\;dt $$

Right?